# How to have a custom data type in OpenAPI?

Tags: typescript, api, openapi, custom-data-type

I'm trying to create a REST API and have different routes to each endpoint to return a value, but it does not accept custom data types such as Date or Coordinate. I have tried to create it but it is still not recognized.

```yaml
  Coordinate:
    type: object
    required:
      - longitude
      - latitude
    properties:
      longitude:
        type: number
        description: longitude for coordinate
      latitude:
        type: number
        description: latitude for coordinate

   facilities:
    properties:
     id:
       type: number
       description: facility Id
     name:
       type: string
       description: facility Name
     coordinates: #this gives an error says invalid data type
       type: Coordinate
       description: facility Coordinate
     address:
       type: string
       description: address of facility
     energyConsumption:
       allOf:
       - type: string
       - type: integer
       - type: boolean
       - type: number
       - type: array
       - type: object
```

I'm supposed to take coordinate like this

```
{(123,123),{2144123,123444)}
```

Comment: Your current `Coordinates` schema corresponds to JSON payload in this format: `{"longitude": 12.34, "latitude": -56.38}`.

Comment: is spouse to, and even if is not it should still say that the data type exist correct?